# Auto move certain filetypes in directory to other

Tags: php, ftp, move, vps

I am trying to get the files .jpg and .dav to be moved from /root to another directory within my VPS. Any help with the code to do so? Thanks.

I have tried google and couldn't really help myself.

Comment: learn a bit of bash and user permissions in Linux

Comment: I think what you need here is `ls` and `mv` commands (for `mv` you may need changing permissions with `chmod` and `chown` or do it as `root` user which is not a recommended practice), however as @kb_ suggested its better to learn more about basic linux commands and permissions. This what I found on Google as the first search result https://maker.pro/linux/tutorial/basic-linux-commands-for-beginners

Answer (score 0):

Most simply answer.
use volume mount over ftp and exec command.

exec('cd /root && find . -type f -name "*.jpg" -o -name "*.dav" |sed -e "s#(.*)#mv \1 /path/to/destination/#g" |sh');